# A lot or Much with the word "Work"

Tags: quantifiers

We had a quiz yesterday and there was this question:

He doesn't have ......... work to do.

1.Many
2.Much
3.A lot of

Kindly answer mentioning a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the answer would be *much.*
Here is why:

> **Much, many with a noun**
>
> We use much with singular uncountable nouns and many with plural nouns:
>
> [talking about money]
>
> *I haven’t got much change. I’ve only got a ten euro note.*
>
> *Are there many campsites near you?*

Apparently *a lot of* is informal and shouldn't be used in this case.

Here is the link with more info on *much, many, a lot of, etc.* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers

Comment: "A lot of" is informal, but there's no reason not to use it in the original example above (unless it's a question of formality).

Comment: @StevenLittman Well, I would assume they are speaking formally for a quiz.

Comment: I am an ESL teacher, and unless I specified that I needed a formal way of saying it, I would accept "a lot of" on a quiz.

Comment: @StevenLittman I would definitely ask if I was taking the quiz. :)

Answer (score 0):

Both make sense, but "much work" sounds more natural.

Comment: You say "both", but there are three choices....

Comment: @Hellion I was referring to the two in the title.